# Spring. Rest API. Java

Tags: java, spring, rest

Работа с телефонной книгой. Пишу серверную часть, хочу созданного пользователя изменить его данные(имя и номер), добавить, удалить, редактировать контакт. Как это сделать? Вот мой код:

```
    // добавить пользователя
@RequestMapping(value = "user/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String addUs(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String number){
    new User(name, number);
    return "Пользователь "+ name +" добавлен!";
}

    // редактировать пользователя пока не работает
@RequestMapping(value = "user/id{id}/edit{name}{number}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String editU(@RequestParam int id,@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String number){
    return user.editUser(name, number);
}

// добавление контакта в телефонную книгу пользователя
@RequestMapping(value = "user/id/addcontact", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String addContact(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String number){
    return addContact(name, number);
}
```

И да, все ли верно я делаю? Есть просто подозрения, что с таким кодом меня отправят в пешее романтическое...

Comment: Скажите в какую сторону идти и что читать, хотя бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/users")
   public class UserController{

       @Autowired
       private UserService userService;


       @GetMapping("/{id}")
       public User get(@PathVariable id){
           return userService.getUser(id);
       }

       // добавить пользователя
       @PostMapping("/")
       public User add(@RequestBody User u){
           return userService.create(u.getName(), u.getNumber());
       }

       // редактировать пользователя пока не работает
       @PutMapping("/{id}")
           public User edit(@PathVariable int id, User u){
           return userService.editUser(u.getName(), u.getNumber());
       }

       @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
       public void delete(@PathVariable id){
           userService.delete(id);
   }
   }
```

Телефонная книга это уже другая сущность, и другой контроллер

```
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/phoneBook")
   public class PhoneBookController{

       @Autowired
       private PhoneBookService phoneBookService;


        // добавление контакта в телефонную книгу пользователя
       @PostMapping("/")
       public User add(@RequestBody User u){
            phoneBoorService.add(u);
            return contact;
       }

       ....

   }
```

Думаю, общее направление понятно.

Comment: Отлично! Но есть одна проблема... что бы спринг нормально работал, то кажется надо создавать интерфейс, верно? Как бы вы сделали приложение где есть пользователи и у них есть телефонные книги с контактами? Я вот создал классы, пользователь и контакты. когда пользователь добавляется то инкрементиуется айди, добавляется пустая телефонная книга.  потом если захочу до пользователю в телефонную книгу добавляю/редактирую/удаляю контакт. И вот по коду который вы писали, я должен сделать еще два класса(или интерфейсы?) которые могут редактировать/добавлять/удалять пользователя и контакты.

Comment: Буду крайне благодарен, если сможете направить меня на путь истинный. Вожусь с этим "приложением" уже долгое время.

Comment: Ни сразу понял что у каждого конкретного пользователя своя телефонная книга должна быть. Я отталкивался от корпоративной системы, где по сути телефонная книга одна на всех. Вам надо определиться с сущностями, тут надо немного больше знать о системе которую вы пишите. Что еще она должна хранить и уметь делать.

Comment: Список пользователей и у каждого из них есть телефонная книга, где есть номера. Также у каждого пользователя есть уникальный айди, как и у контактов. Я должен уметь каждого пользователя добавлять, удалять, редактировать, находить, добавлять новый контакт в его справочник. Также с контактами(добавлять, удалять, редактировать, находить). Метода я уже написал, но проблема оказалась в сущностях! Я сделал только три класса(контакт, пользователь, маин). Списки пользователй инкрементирутся в конструкторе.

Comment: Я вот пытаюсь подружиться со спрингом. Но что-то не получается, а именно с внедрениями

Comment: Контактами могут быть только пользователи или любые другие люди?

Comment: По сущностям у меня пока рисуется такая картина: `class Person { private String family, private String firstName, private String lastName, ...}`, `class Contact{ private Person person, private String phoneNumber, ... }`, `class PhoneBook{ private User user, private List<Contact> contacts, ...}`, `class User{ private Person person, private String username, private String password, ...}`

Comment: Что касается внедрения зависимостей. Внедрять можно только компоненты, т.е. классы помеченные одной из аннотаций `@Component`, `@Service`,`@Repository`, `@Controller` и т.д. любая из аннотаций наследуемая от @Component.  Все эти бины создаются как синглетоны в момент запуска приложения. Для внедрения зависимости (получение ссылки на имеющийся синглетон) достаточно над переменной прописать аннотацию @Autowired. Например: `@Repository public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long>{}`, `@Service public class UserService{ @Autovared private UserRepository repo; }`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102430/discussion-between-atata174-and-z-john).